# Create empty directory in RPM using gradle.buildRpm

Tags: java, gradle, rpm

I'm using `com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:5.1.0` plugin for Gradle to pack distribution into RPM.

Now I need to create an empty dir inside RPM. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in [documentation](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin):
Specifies directory that should be created within package.

```
directory(String path, int permissions)
```

However, there is not mention where to apply such property. `directory` will work in `buildRpm` section only and this is very important:

```
buildRpm {
...
directory('/opt/hazelcast-srv/logs')
```

}